# Ajuda com validação de textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera boa tarde.

Estou com dificuldade de realizar uma tarefa, que é a seguinte:

tenho um cadastro de cliente, que quando o usuário edita alguma coisa do cadastro, ao salvar é apresentado uma tela, para ele indicar o motivo da alteração, porem nesta tela, nao pode deixar o motivo em branco, ai que entra o problema..

Estou utilizando IF para verificar se esta preenchido ou não, porem mesmo ele caindo no else e exibindo minha mensagem de aviso, ele fecha a tela e volta para a tela de cadastro de cliente,

Na tela de cadastro de cliente, ao clicar no botão salvar, executa o codigo:

```
        else if (editar == 1)
        {
            Observacao_cliente obs = new Observacao_cliente(id_cliente); // verificar qual tipo de retorno para poder cadastrar a atualização.

            if (obs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                chek_new_cli = cadastro_bd.cadastro_cliente(editar, textBox13.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox15.Text, textBox16.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text, comboBox1.Text, bloq_v, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox14.Text);

                if (chek_new_cli > 0)
                { 
                   //inicia o cadastro no banco....
```

No form observação_cliente, ao clicar no botão salvar, executa o codigo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botão salvar
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text != string.Empty && textBox2.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            check_salvar = cadastro.cadastro_obs_cliente(id_cliente, dateTimePicker1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

            if (check_salvar > 0)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O título e nem o motivo podem estar em branco!", "Observações Gerais", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou tratar o evento OnClose do Form? No onclose você fará´o teste se o campo estiver vazio e não muda o estado impedindo que o evento continue.

Comment: OnClose? vou pesquisar sobre. Obrigado.

Comment: Leia este artigo que mostra como funciona o tratamento do evento [Artigo MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado. consegui resolver com a sua ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode realizar o tratamento do evento OnClose do formulário. Este é o evento que é chamado após o método Close ser chamado. Nele você pode especificar se realmente você poder fechar.

O [artigo do MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) explica bem. Dê uma olhada na [propriedade Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) na documentação

E a partir daí, você trata da melhor forma que sua regra permitir:

```
e.Cancel = true;
MessageBox.Show("Opa! Não consigo fechar porque...");
```

ou

```
e.Cancel = false;
MessageBox.Show("Já posso fechar a tela. Adeus!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigos boa tarde.

Apos a ajuda do nosso colega, Andre Mesquita, consegui resolver, adicionando o evento abaixo.

```
        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(check_salvar == 0)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Valeu