# Enquanto o valor the progressbar não chegar a 100 não fecha a janela

Tags: c#

Antes de começar não é mesmo um vírus e sim um jogo. Eu queria que enquanto a progressbar não chegar a 100% não pudesse fechar a janela ao clicar o botão e apareça um popup a dizer que não pode fechar está aqui o código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value != 100)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (progressBar1.Value > 100)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to wait the virus download");
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa do evento OnClose do formulário. Respondi recentemente esta pergunta no [SOpt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141932/21263).

Comment: **`progressBar1.Value > 100`**????

Comment: o que está errado?

Comment: Está ao contrário... Leia isso como **`se o valor da progressbar for MAIOR que 100`**.

Comment: ok obrigado pela ajuda mas ainda nao está resolvido

Comment: Sim, jovem. Isso foi só um comentário. A resposta está ali embaixo.

Comment: Já descobri uma solução obrigado a quem tentou ajudar me

Comment: Qual foi a solução? Fiquei curioso :)

Comment: fiz com que quando a barra chegasse a 100% aparecesse o botão para fechar a janela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o Evento OnFormClosing:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    if (progressBar.Value < 100) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mensagem de alerta, não feche ainda!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form

Comment: não está a dar esta a dar errado  na parte de (progressBar < 100)

Comment: @Pekira Diga qual o erro/problema, caso contrário o autor da resposta não vai ter como lhe ajudar...

Comment: continua sem dar o visual studio acusa que o código esta errado

Comment: @Pekira Sim, mas o que o "Visual Studio diz", jovem? Nos ajude a te ajudar...

Comment: opperator < cannot be applied to operators of type "progressBar" and "int"

Comment: Pronto, jovem. Editei a resposta. Você deveria ter percebido isso, não acha?

Comment: Salve jovens! Só vi agora que minha resposta não tinha colocado a propriedade Value. Mas não preocupei tanto na hora da resposta. A ideia era exemplificar o método OnFormClosing.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Shura16 está absolutamente correta. O problema que você encontra ao compilar a resposta dele é no nome do seu progressbar. Pelo que vi, seu progressbar está nomeado como "progressBar1"

Tente copiar a resposta abaixo:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    if (progressBar1.Value < 100) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mensagem de alerta, não feche ainda!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```